ListView Builder Horizontal Scroll Not Working
This is my widget within a column for my windows app, my goal is to implement a horizontal scroll section. The issues is that the I use two fingers to scroll horizontally nothing happens.
SizedBox(
height: 100, 
child: Scrollbar(
  // Added a scrollbar
  child: ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: serviceCategory.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
        child: ServiceTile(
          categoryImageUrl: serviceCategory[index][0],
          categoryName: serviceCategory[index][1],
          categoryImageRadius: 22,
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
),

However when I turn comment out the scroll direction for the horizontal scroll, it scrolls vertically

What do you have in ServiceTile, ig it is trying to take infinite width.

You would need to define the width property for it to work
SizedBox(
height: 100, 
width: 100, // <-- HERE
child: Scrollbar(
  // Added a scrollbar
  child: ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: serviceCategory.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
        child: ServiceTile(
          categoryImageUrl: serviceCategory[index][0],
          categoryName: serviceCategory[index][1],
          categoryImageRadius: 22,
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
),

If the problem persists there might be a problem with the ServiceTile widget.

It didn’t work. I went as far as replacing the ServiceTile with a container red Container of 40 by 40 size. When I comment out the horizontal it works

@Uche, something like this is perfectly scrolling for me, try running this code on Dartpad. If there is something I am missing, please correct me.
https://gist.github.com/ShashankDeepak/16cea9a08e96b01c175c9ad5880cd6e0

It works on Dartpad even with my service tile, did you try running it for desktop(windows)?
